# Android app keeps stopping on Ionic 5 framework

Tags: android, ionic-framework, frameworks

Good day! Could anyone suggest please … am working on Ionic 5 app which was working great in all device but suddenly It was closing immediately after I downloding data from server and writing it to the database.

When I started app it again it show splash screen and message app keeps stopping. I do not understand what is problem happend? I did not change anything but app dose not started.

how to get Native logs (logcat) from android on windows ?

Ionic info:

**Ionic:**

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.1.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.10
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.10
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.10
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 23 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v12.15.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.13.4
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Comment: Hey, I am also facing this issue for some devices, did you find any solutions?